# Dafny reports "Resolution failed". Why, this seems fine with me

Tags: dafny

I am working through the exercises of Leino's book "Program Proofs" and tried for Exercise 1.9 the following:

```
method Triple(x: int) returns (r: int)
  ensures r == 3*x
{
  r := 3*x;
}

function Average(a: int, b: int): int {
  (a + b)/2
}

method Triple'(x: int) returns (r: int) 
  ensures Average(r, 3*x) == 3*x
  ensures r%3 == 0
{
  r := 3*x;
}

method EquivalentSpecs(x: int)
{
  var a := Triple(x);
  var b := Triple'(x);
  assert a == b;
}

method EquivalentSpecs'(x: int)
{
  assert Triple(x) == Triple'(x);
}
```

`

The problem is that the verifier reports "Resolution Failed" for EquivalentSpecs' while it has no problem with EquivalentSpecs (which in my view is much less natural).
Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

In `EquivalentSpecs'()` you have this:

```dafny
assert Triple(x) == Triple'(x);
```

Here you are making a method call from within an expression, which is not allowed in Dafny. The only thing you can do with a method call is assign its result directly to a variable.  So, you would translate the above statement by using two temporary variables:

```dafny
var tmp1 := Triple(x);
var tmp2 := Triple'(x);
assert tmp1 == tmp2;
```

This is exactly what you've done in `EquivalentSpecs()`!  Another example is the following:

```dafny
method f(x:int) returns (r:int) {
    r := Triple(x) + 1;
}
```

Again, Dafny won't like this.  Instead, we have to translate it as follows:

```dafny
method f(x:int) returns (r:int) {
    var tmp := Triple(x);
    r := tmp + 1;
}
```

The reason for this unusual behaviour is that Dafny requires  expressions to be [side-effect free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 0):

In Dafny method call is statement (https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-update-and-call-statement), it is used here in expression which is not allowed.